# Remove empty item from select drop down angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to bind data to select drop down using AngularJS ng-repeat directive but it's showing an empty data on page load. How to remove the empty item.
Here is the code:

```
    <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
      <select ng-model="selected">
        <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.id}}">
          {{item.name}}
        </option>
      </select>
      <span>
        {{selected}}
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
            app.controller('homeCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
                $scope.selected = 1;
                $scope.items=[
                    {name: 'harry111',id:1},
                    {name: 'rimmi',id:2}
                ];

            }]);
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqZVjb?editors=1010)

Comment: Look at the answer being posted. That is what you need.

Comment: The answer is simple and posted by @SrinivasML, but better use ng-options instead as a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make `$scope.selected = 1;` as `$scope.selected = "1";`  it will default select a value

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
   app.controller('homeCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
     $scope.selected = "1";
    $scope.items=[
     {name: 'harry111',id:1},
     {name: 'rimmi',id:2}
    ];
        
       
         
       
    
   }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
      <select ng-model="selected">
        <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.id}}">
          {{item.name}}
        </option>
      </select>
      <span>
        {{selected}}
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why "1" and not 1 ?

Comment: I am searching for this issue , I had faced this issue once when converted to string it got selected , checking SO questions to add reference

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `ng-repeat` on `<select>` tag like this

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
      <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="value.id as value.name
                                           for (key,value) in items"
  ></select>
      <span>
        {{selected}}
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will not add the blank option in the select dropdown. Here is the working [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgxaWL?editors=1010)

Comment: but I dont see ng -repeat

Comment: See that, there is ng-option that iterates over the items array.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-options instead,

```
 ng-options="value.id as value.name for (key,value) in items"
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
   app.controller('homeCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.items=[
     {name: 'harry111',id:1},
     {name: 'rimmi',id:2}
    ];
       $scope.selected = $scope.items[0].id;
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
     <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="value.id as value.name
                                           for (key,value) in items"
  ></select>
      <span>
        {{selected}}
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```