# Select option using ng-repeat not selecting if assigned value is Number , Angular 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I came across a peculiar issue in **Angular 1.6** , same code is **working fine for Angular 1.2** , When we try to assign selected value of dropdown created by ng-repeat using a Number it is not getting selected but model value is assigned.

Check example below , I have assigned  `$scope.selectedOne = 1;` with number and 
 `$scope.selectedTwo = "1";` with a string , First drop down is not getting selected whereas second drop down is getting selected. I am using same items for both drop down. The same piece of code is working fine in Angular 1.2(Selecting for both cases).

Can anyone please explain difference in these two versions

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedOne = 1;
  $scope.selectedTwo = "1";
  $scope.items = [{
      name: 'harry111',
      id: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'rimmi',
      id: 2
    }
  ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedOne">
        <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.id}}">
          {{item.name}}
        </option>
      </select>
    <div>
      selectedOne :{{selectedOne}}
    </div>
    <select ng-model="selectedTwo">
        <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.id}}">
          {{item.name}}
        </option>
      </select>
    <div>
      selectedOne :{{selectedOne}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

After answering *stackoverflow.com/questions/44799901/…* this question I came across this issue , which worked fine with Angular 1.2(Selecting for both cases).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty item from select drop down angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799901/remove-empty-item-from-select-drop-down-angularjs)

Comment: U should take a look at NgOptions instead of using NgRepeat on option tag

Comment: After answering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799901/remove-empty-item-from-select-drop-down-angularjs this question I came across this issue , which worked fine with Angular 1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This change actually happened during migration from **angularjs 1.3 to 1.4**, so from the migration release [**guide doc**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-3-to-1-4) :

> Due to **7fda214c**, the select directive will now use strict comparison
>   of the ngModel scope value against option values to determine which
>   option is selected. This means non-string scope values (such as Number
>   or Boolean) will not be matched against equivalent option strings
>   (such as the strings "123", "true" or "false").

to fix this use `ng-value`, Demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.change = function() {
  alert(typeof $scope.selectedOne ); 
  alert(typeof $scope.selectedTwo ); 
  }
  $scope.selectedOne = 1;
  $scope.selectedTwo = "1";
  $scope.items = [{
      name: 'harry111',
      id: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'rimmi',
      id: 2
    }
  ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <select ng-change="change()" ng-model="selectedOne">
        <option ng-repeat="item in items" ng-value="{{item.id}}">
          {{item.name}}
        </option>
      </select>
    <div>
      selectedOne :{{selectedOne}}
    </div>
    <select ng-change="change()" ng-model="selectedTwo">
        <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.id}}">
          {{item.name}}
        </option>
      </select>
    <div>
      selectedOne :{{selectedOne}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Matching model and option values:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#matching-model-and-option-values)

> If you are setting the option value with the option's value attribute,
>   or textContent, the value will always be a string which means that the
>   model value must also be a string. Otherwise the select directive
>   cannot match them correctly.

There are also different strategies on how to bind the model to a non-string value.

It works for **AngularJS v1.2** since this changes were introduced in **v1.4** - take a look at this [migration guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-3-to-1-4):

> Due to [`7fda214c`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7fda214c4f65a6a06b25cf5d5aff013a364e9cef), the `select` directive will now use strict comparison
>   of the `ngModel` scope value against `option` values to determine which
>   option is selected. This means non-string scope values (such as `Number`
>   or `Boolean`) will not be matched against equivalent option strings
>   (such as the strings `"123"`, `"true"` or `"false"`).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with v1.6, ngValue will also set the value property of the element (in addition to the value attribute). It might not affect your use case, but it's another difference worth keeping in mind.

kindly take a look for this below discussion:

[What is the difference between `value` attribute and `ng-value` attributes in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865608/what-is-the-difference-between-value-attribute-and-ng-value-attributes-in-an)